# Vue failed to compile(related to export? )

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm doing my first project using Vue, so I'm not familiar with this.

While I was trying to run the project(npm run serve) on the other laptop, I met below error.

What am I missing?

It worked well before..

I'm using macOS, vue3 (vue-cli 4), and removed all xattr

Could you help me to fix this error?

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (4:9)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
 * ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| 
| export default class User {
>   userId = "";
|   userNm = "";
|   userPwd = "";

 @ ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist??ref--0-1!./src/views/....vue?vue&type=script&lang=js 5:0-32 35:20-24 67:28-32
 ...
 @ ./src/router/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.50.11:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js
```

These are dependencies.

```
"dependencies": {
"@chenfengyuan/vue-countdown": "^2.0.0-rc",
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.36",
"@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
"@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
"@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^3.0.0-4",
"axios": "^0.21.4",
"bootstrap": "^5.1.1",
"core-js": "^3.6.5",
"path": "^0.12.7",
"primeicons": "^4.1.0",
"primevue": "^3.7.2",
"vue": "^3.0.0",
"vue-router": "^4.0.0-0",
"vuex": "^4.0.0-0"},



"devDependencies": {
"@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
"@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
"@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
"@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.0",
"@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
"@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
"@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0",
"babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
"eslint": "^6.7.2",
"eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
"eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0",
"prettier": "^2.2.1",
"sass": "^1.26.5",
"sass-loader": "^8.0.2"
```

}

Comment: [Class field declarations are a stage 3 feature](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) and not part of the ECMAScript standard yet. (It's upcoming for ES2022.) You might have to configure Babel accordingly if you want to use them.

Comment: If you have a similar issue with server-aide code, check your node version. Public class fields were added in node 12

Comment: @CherryDT  
node - v14.17.6 
npm - 7.24.1 
vue/cli - 4.5.13

babel is included and vue is 14..